# Chrome Dev Tools: Modifying / Extending (beyond the API)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is the only way to extend the Chrome dev tools via these APIs?

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.html

They seem pretty limited. I would want to be able to do things like filter things that have been logged / written to the console, search,  pattern match, etc.

Even being able to do something like log everything but warnings (and errors) would be a simple addition I would like to do.

I can add other examples but I believe, if I'm correct, I will have to build Chrome from source?

I already run Canary and regular Chrome, I am wondering if it will run along these two?

I've read and tried to build Chrome on Mac but it didn't really work from the guide I followed, perhaps doing it on Ubuntu is easier? My goal is not to fix bugs in Chrome, just to extend it and keep it up to date with the Canary or a stable build.

Thank you.

PS: I do mostly javascript now but I used to work on systems so  I am not afraid to write C++/C if I have to. However, I think the dev tools are mostly HTML/ JS themselves?

Comment: you can already log only errors and logs and debug by hold [CTRL] while you click the error types under the console.